# How to create a customized Invoice Report . Odoo 14

Tags: javascript, python, xml, odoo

I need to customise the invoice format : header , footer , page , and replace the existing one.
I tried with this solution , but when printing the invoice , I got an empty document.
Any help please ?
Here is my code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data>
        <record id="account_invoices" model="ir.actions.report">
            <field name="name">Invoices</field>
            <field name="model">account.move</field>
            <field name="report_type">qweb-pdf</field>
            <field name="report_name">my_module.report_invoice_with_payments</field>
            <field name="report_file">my_module.report_invoice_with_payments</field>
            <field name="print_report_name">(object._get_report_base_filename())</field>
            <field name="attachment">(object.state == 'posted') and ((object.name or 'INV').replace('/','_')+'.pdf')</field>
            <field name="binding_model_id" ref="model_account_move"/>
            <field name="binding_type">report</field>
            <field name="groups_id" eval="[(4, ref('account.group_account_invoice')),
 (4, ref('account.group_account_readonly'))]"/>
        </record>




 <template id="report_invoice_with_payments">
            <t t-call="web.html_container">

                <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
                <div class="article" t-attf-data-oe-model="account.move" t-attf-data-oe-id="{{o.id}}">
                </div>
                    <t t-set="lang" t-value="o.invoice_user_id.sudo().lang if o.move_type in ('in_invoice', 'in_refund') else o.partner_id.lang"/>
                    <t t-set="print_with_payments" t-value="True"/>
                    <t t-if="o._get_name_invoice_report() == 'my_module.new_report_invoice_document'"
                        t-call="my_module.new_report_invoice_document" t-lang="lang"/>
                </t>
            </t>
        </template>
</data>
</odoo>


<template id="new_report_invoice_document">
            <t t-call="web.external_layout">
....
</template>
```

Is there any other solution to do it ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I did this recently. I think you can do it in two ways these are given below. Go to **Odoo settings** then **Business Documents** section and from there go to **Document Layout**. Here you can edit the code as your need and this will apply to all over the documents. Here **header** class represents the header. You have to change each template if you want to customize all the things. You can find all the templates from **technical > user Interface > views** settings.
[image]

[image]

But if you want to do it by custom module then you need to inherit and replace the changes with existing ones. But here you can make another invoice option without replacing the existing ones. By the way, I am giving you the sample code that works for me:

```
<!-- Custom invoice without payment -->
 <template id="module_name.template_id">
    <!--        <t t-call="web.html_container">-->
    <t t-call="web.basic_layout">
        <!--            <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="doc">-->
        <div class="oe_structure"/>
        <t t-if="not o" t-set="o" t-value="docs"/>

        <t t-if="not company">
            <!-- Multicompany -->
            <t t-if="company_id">
                <t t-set="company" t-value="company_id"/>
            </t>
            <t t-elif="o and 'company_id' in o">
                <t t-set="company" t-value="o.company_id.sudo()"/>
            </t>
            <t t-else="else">
                <t t-set="company" t-value="res_company"/>
            </t>
        </t>

        <t t-esc="company.update_scss()"/>
        <t t-set="docs" t-value="o.with_context(lang=lang)"/>
        <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
          <!-- Here goes the custom design for the invoice -->
        </t>
    </t>
</template>

<!-- Custom invoice with payment -->
<template id="your_module.template_id" inherit_id="your_module.template_id_from_above_module"
          primary="True">
    <xpath expr="x_path_of_where_you_put_the_payment_section" position="after">
        <t t-set="payments_vals" t-value="o._get_reconciled_info_JSON_values()"/>
        <t t-set="total_paid" t-value="0"/>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <hr class="m-1"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <!-- Show partial payments -->
        <t t-foreach="payments_vals" t-as="payment_vals">
            <t t-set="total_paid" t-value="total_paid + payment_vals['amount']"/>
            <tr>
                <td class="text-right">
                    <i class="oe_form_field text-right oe_payment_label">Paid on
                        <t t-esc="payment_vals['date']" t-options='{"widget": "date"}'/>:
                    </i>
                </td>
                <td class="text-right">
                    <span t-esc="payment_vals['amount']"
                          t-options='{"widget": "monetary", "display_currency": o.currency_id}'/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </t>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <hr class="m-1"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="text-right">
                <strong>Total Paid:</strong>
            </td>
            <td class="text-right">
                <strong t-esc="total_paid"
                        t-options='{"widget": "monetary", "display_currency": o.currency_id}'/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <!-- End Show partial payments -->
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <hr class="m-1"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="text-right">
                <span t-if="o.previous_due">Amount Due:</span>
                <strong t-else="">Amount Due:</strong>
            </td>
            <td class="text-right">
                <span t-if="o.previous_due" t-field="o.amount_residual"/>
                <strong t-else="" t-field="o.amount_residual"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr t-if="o.previous_due">
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <hr class="m-1"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr t-if="o.previous_due">
            <td class="text-right">
                <strong>Total Due:</strong>
            </td>
            <td class="text-right">
                <strong t-field="o.total_due"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xpath>
</template>
```